# ResponsiveSlides.js & Wordpress Images Not Appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to integrate ResponsiveSlides.js into my wordpress designs, and I think I more or less migrated the JQuery plugin to Wordpress format correctly, but the images refuse to load for some reason. Here is a link to the test wordpress theme I'm building:

www.azletconsulting.com

my functions.php code is here:

```
  function responsive_slides() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryui' );
    wp_register_script( 'responsiveslides', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/responsiveslides.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'responsiveslides' );
    wp_register_style('responsiveslidescss', get_template_directory_uri(). '/responsiveslides.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('responsiveslidescss');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'responsive_slides');
```

My HTML page code is here:

```
<section class="main">
    <div class="front_slide">
        <ul id="slider1" class="rslides rslides1">
            <li id="rlslides1_s0" class="" style="display: block; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; transition: opacity 900ms ease-in-out 0s;">
                <img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/test1.png">
            </li>
            <li id="rlslides1_s1" class="" style="display: block; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; transition: opacity 900ms ease-in-out 0s;">
                <img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/test2.png">
            </li>
            <li id="rlslides1_s2" class="" style="display: block; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; transition: opacity 900ms ease-in-out 0s;">
                <img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/test3.png">
            </li>
            <li id="rlslides1_s3" class="" style="display: block; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; transition: opacity 900ms ease-in-out 0s;">
                <img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/test4.png">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main_header">




   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.rslides1').responsive_slides();
   </script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Provided link shows a blank page. There is HTML in the source however. Console says `jQuery(...).responsiveSlides is not a function.`

Comment: Sorry I fixed it back to responsive_slides(), which should be correct since that is in the defined function in the functions.php file as shown above.

Comment: `responsive_slides is not a function`. You need to use the console to figure out what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the slider you're using?  http://responsiveslides.com/

In that case, change `responsive_slides()` to `responsiveSlides()`

```
jQuery('.rslides1').responsiveSlides();
```

**Edit:** I have copied over the HTML content to my local server along with all resources, and I can confirm that making that small change works.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, that fixed it! I guess the function it is calling the function from the .js file instead of what I called the function in functions.php to load it into my header. This was my first time trying to incorporate a jquery plugin into wordpress so thanks for helping out.